# Selecting multiple values from same column with a single Select query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, statements

So, I've got two tables: users and tasks;

users:

```
 user_id    username    password    first_name  last_name   isAdmin
```

tasks:

```
 task_id    name    description     assessment  assigned_user_id fk creator_id fk   created_on  last_modified   status
```

What I want to do is replace `assigned_user_id` and `creator_id` with `first_name` + `last_name` from users table. So I execute the following query:

```
SELECT `task_id`, `description`,`assessment`, 
(SELECT CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ',`last_name`) WHERE `Tasks`.`assigned_user_id` = `Users`.`user_id`) AS assigned_user, 
(SELECT CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ',`last_name`) WHERE `Tasks`.`creator_id`=`Users`.`user_id`) AS creator_user,
`created_on`,`last_modified`,`status`
FROM `Tasks`
LEFT JOIN `Users`
ON Tasks.assigned_user_id = Users.user_id 
OR Tasks.creator_id =  Users.user_id
WHERE task_id=2
```

The problem is that it returns 2 rows. One is with `assigned_user_id null` and filled `creator_id` and the other is the other way around:

```
 task_id    description     assessment  assigned_user   creator_user    created_on  last_modified   status
  2         SHA SA PII LI   24          NULL            Petyo Chuliuv   2016-07-22  2016-07-22       1
  2         SHA SA PII LI   24          Gosho Toshov            NULL    2016-07-22  2016-07-22       1
```

Question is: How to return a single row with `assigned_user` and `creator_user` filled and where I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to your users table twice and alias them...

Somethin like...

```
SELECT `task_id`, `description`,`assessment`, 
(SELECT CONCAT(`assignedUsers.first_name`, ' ',`assignedUsers.last_name`)  AS assigned_user, 
(SELECT CONCAT(`createdUsers.first_name`, ' ',`createdUsers.last_name`)  AS creator_user,
`created_on`,`last_modified`,`status`
FROM `Tasks`
LEFT JOIN `Users` assignedUsers ON Tasks.assigned_user_id = assignedUsers .user_id 
LEFT JOIN `Users` createdUsers ON Tasks.creator_id = createdUsers .user_id 
WHERE task_id=2
```

Comment: assignedUsers and createdUsers?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two foreign keys and you want to fetch the corresponding data you just have to INNER JOIN the `users` table twice.

You used LEFT JOIN which will fetch all the data from the first table,in your case `tasks`, even if no match is found in the second table (in your case this did not made any difference but in cases where an id is not set or the user does not exist anymore maybe this is a problem that is up to you to decide...) and you also used `OR` in the JOIN conditions which resulted in duplicate tasks in the results.

So you must INNER JOIN twice.One time to get the assigned user and one to get the creator.

Havent tested but this should work :

```
SELECT t.`task_id`, t.`description`,t.`assessment`,
       CONCAT(u1.`firstname`,' ',u1.`lastname`) as creator,
       CONCAT(u2.`firstname`,' ',u2.`lastname`) as assigned_user,
       t.`created_on`,t.`last_modified`,t.`status` 
FROM `tasks` t 
INNER JOIN `users` u1 ON t.creator_id=u1.id
INNER JOIN `users` u2 ON t.assigned_user_id=u2.id
WHERE t.`task_id`=2
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on SQL Server and reproduced the same issue as you so hopefully I can be of help.

When I did the test the two `SELECT CONCAT` statements were using the same user_id both times.  So the issue seems that it is not checking for both ids at once but both ids at separate times. So if I were to use your example it first uses Petyo's id in both of the `SELECT CONCAT` statements (only filling the `creator_user` role so the other one becomes false) and then it uses Gosho's id in both of the `SELECT CONCAT` statements which also only fills one field (the `assigned_user` field) and making the other one null.

So what you need to do is `JOIN` the `Users` table again.  One for the assigned, one for the create.  Something like this...

```
SELECT `task_id`, `description`,`assessment`, 
(SELECT CONCAT(`U1.first_name`, ' ',`U1.last_name`)) AS assigned_user, 
(SELECT CONCAT(`U2.first_name`, ' ',`U2.last_name`)) AS creator_user,
`created_on`,`last_modified`,`status`
FROM `Tasks`
LEFT JOIN `Users` U1
ON Tasks.assigned_user_id = U1.user_id 
LEFT JOIN `Users` U2
ON Tasks.creator_id = U2.user_id
WHERE task_id=2
```

Before you had an `OR`.  It does not look at one side, look for the id, then look at the other one, look for the id, then use it at once.  It is exactly that.  If the current `user_id` it is looking for happens to be one of those two then it uses that single `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys but I fixed it by doing:

```
SELECT `task_id`, `description`,`assessment`, 
(SELECT CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`)
FROM `Users` 
WHERE `Tasks`.`assigned_user_id` = `Users`.`user_id`)  AS assigned_user, 
(SELECT CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) 
FROM `Users` 
WHERE `Tasks`.`creator_id`=`Users`.`user_id`) AS creator_user,
`created_on`,`last_modified`,`status`
FROM `Tasks`
WHERE task_id=3
```

I just added `FROM Users` and `WHERE` clauses in each inner `SELECT`,
so I didn't have to do any joins... As always it was way more simple than I thought. Thanks again, much appreciated!

Comment: Using SUB SELECTS is a good solution too.Generally JOINS are preffered especially in mysql because most of the time you get a much better performance(especially in older versions of mysql server).But that also depends on the query itself and the mysql server version you are using.You should compare both queries performance to see what is best for you.